# Convert #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation to #<ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Ok, so I'm getting an error breaking my code when the @products array is `#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation` when it's `#<ActiveRecord::Relation` everything works fine

```
    if params[:collection_id] && params[:collection_id] != ""
      @products = Collection.find_by(id: params[:collection_id]).products.not_hidden
    else
      @products = Product.for_company(@current_company).not_hidden.where(category_id: @category.subtree.visible.ids)
    end
    puts("===============")
    puts @products.inspect
    puts("===============")
```

First case, which causes the error, returns

```
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Product id: 29, bar_code: "", deleted: false, price: 3242.0, discounted_price: 52.0, category_id: 15, tags: "", created_at: "2020-12-14 12:29:04", updated_at: "2020-12-17 14:45:26", final_price: 52.0, status: "visible", sku: "", barcode: "", priority: 100, min_quantity: 1, max_quantity: 100, add_shipping_fees: true, weight: 0.0, inventory: {"jklj"=>{"sku"=>"", "barcode"=>"", "quantity"=>"13"}, "ojio9"=>{"sku"=>"", "barcode"=>"", "quantity"=>"555"}}, add_to_inventory: true, is_translated: true, requires_preparing: false, name: "product englishh", description: "">]>
```

Second case, which works fine, returns

```
 #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Product id: 28, bar_code: "", deleted: false, price: 21312.0, discounted_price: 23.0, category_id: 16, tags: "", created_at: "2020-12-10 12:03:37", updated_at: "2020-12-14 13:45:17", final_price: 23.0, status: "visible", sku: "", barcode: "", priority: 100, min_quantity: 1, max_quantity: 234, add_shipping_fees: true, weight: 0.0, inventory: {"ewqeqwr"=>{"sku"=>"", "barcode"=>"", "quantity"=>"0"}}, add_to_inventory: true, is_translated: true, requires_preparing: false, name: "ewqeqwr", description: "<p>qweqw</p>\r\n">,]>
```

So you can see that the only difference is that the one breaking is AssociationRelation instead of Relation, how can I convert it to Relation?

The error is the following:

```
PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  cannot call jsonb_each on a non-object
: SELECT  DISTINCT "products"."priority" AS alias_0, "products"."id" AS alias_1, "products"."id" FROM "products" LEFT OUTER JOIN "product_translations" ON "product_translations"."product_id" = "products"."id" INNER JOIN "collection_products" ON "products"."id" = "collection_products"."product_id" WHERE "products"."deleted" = $1 AND "collection_products"."collection_id" = $2 AND "products"."status" IN ($3, $4) AND "products"."status" = $5 AND (add_to_inventory =FALSE OR (add_to_inventory =TRUE AND inventory !='{}' )) AND NOT (ARRAY(select distinct (jsonb_each(inventory)).value->>'quantity' as integer)='{0}') ORDER BY "products"."priority" ASC, "products"."id" ASC LIMIT $6 OFFSET $7 excluded from capture: Not configured to send/capture in environment 'development'
```

The json_b each run happens here

```
@products = @products.offset(offset)
           .limit(@limit)
           .where(status: "visible")
           .where("add_to_inventory =? OR (add_to_inventory =? AND inventory !=? )", false, true, "{}")
           .where.not("ARRAY(select distinct (jsonb_each(inventory)).value->>'quantity' as integer)='{0}'")
```

Comment: The problem will be in the `jsonb_each(inventory)` section, which means that you have either something broken, or null in that field. What happens when you run the generated SQL in pgAdmin (or similar)?

Comment: I changed my code, both are ActiveRecord::Relations and I even made sure they include the same stuff, I got an exact print of @products.inspect before both cases but still one breaks and one doesn't so it doesn't make any sense to me.